# hide column or range of column, column number enter in input box

Tags: excel, vba

need a VBA coding for hide a single column or range of column with specific column number enter in inputbox.
for example if I run a macro, input box occur for taking the value, then I enter B, then it will hide column number B.
same if I enter C:Z then it would hide column C to Z.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the macro's code:

```
Sub HideColumns()
    Dim colRange As Variant
    colRange = InputBox("Enter a column name or range to hide, e.g. A or A:C")
    Columns(colRange).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```